# Thread in static constructor not work instantly

Tags: c#

I have a static Thread which is responsible for get and update the token from remote api. I want to start that thread in a static constructor like below

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace StaticConstructor
{
    public class CallBack
    {
        static string _token = "init";
        static Thread _threadUpdateToken;
        static CallBack()
        {
            _threadUpdateToken = new Thread(()=>
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < 3)
                {
                    GetTokenFromAPI();
                    Thread.Sleep(1 * 1000);
                    i++;
                }
            });
            _threadUpdateToken.Start();
            Console.WriteLine($"After thread start {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")}");
            Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000);
            Console.WriteLine($"Static constructor keep running at {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")}");
            Console.WriteLine($"token = {_token}");
        }

        public static void GetTokenFromAPI()
        {
            //this is for demo purpose
            var rd = new Random();
            _token = rd.Next().ToString();
            Console.WriteLine($"token has been updated as {_token} at {DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")}");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CallBack cb = new CallBack();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
After _threadUpdateToken.Start 05:16:15
Static constructor keeps running at 05:16:25
token = init
token has been updated as 1671358759 at 05:16:25
token has been updated as 437230378 at 05:16:26
token has been updated as 1350585644 at 05:16:27
```

Then my question is:

1. Why thread _threadUpdateToken not start before static Constructor finished? Is that because static Constructor must be finished before any other threads access static variables?

2. What should i do if i dont want to invoke GetTokenFromAPI() directly in static Constructor like

```
static CallBack()
        {
            GetTokenFromAPI();
        }
```

Comment: In regards to your first question threads don't spin up instantly, actually this is all a little contrived and probably more than a bit XY'ish

Comment: I know. Thats why i added Thread.Sleep(). Even no matter how you set  Thread's priority, it will not start.

Comment: @TheGeneral It's not about threads spinning up quickly, it's down to how static constructors work. I do agree this code is a bit smelly though.

Comment: @DavidG ahh yeah i see what you mean, good point

Comment: @DavidG can you please give me some advise?

Comment: Um yeah, don't do it this way!

Comment: So that means i should invoke GetTokenFromAPI() directly in the static constructor?

Answer (score 1):

From the [C# docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors):

> A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or **any static members are referenced**.

So what is happening here is that your thread will run right up to the point it tries to call the `GetTokenFromAPI` static method, wait until the static constructor ends and then carry on.